# Update database tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following database tables : [image]

In these tables I have the following elements :

- Container : Can contain any container_item element; The relation is stored using the table CONTAINER_CANDIDATES
- Container_Item: Can contain any element item; The relation is stored using the table COMPOUNDS
- Elements: The basic element in my system.

Let me phrase the question using a concrete case:

In the table ELEMENTS I can store the following elements:

```
Id = 1 ; ElementName = 'element001'
Id = 2 ; ElementName = 'element002'
Id = 3 ; ElementName = 'element003'
Id = 4 ; ElementName = 'element004'
Id = 5 ; ElementName = 'element005'
Id = 6 ; ElementName = 'element006'
Id = 7 ; ElementName = 'element007'
```

In table CONTAINER_ITEM I can store the following elements:

```
Id = 1 ; ContainerItemName = 'item-id-aaa'
Id = 2 ; ContainerItemName = 'item-id-bbb'
Id = 3 ; ContainerItemName = 'item-id-ccc'
Id = 4 ; ContainerItemName = 'item-id-ddd'
Id = 5 ; ContainerItemName = 'item-id-eee'
```

In table CONTAINER, I can store the following elements:

```
Id = 1; ContainerName = 'ContainerName01';
Id = 2; ContainerName = 'ContainerName02';
```

Using the table COMPOUNDS I make the following connections:

```
    - item-id-aaa  (id = 1 in Container_Item table)
        -> element001 (id = 1 in Elements table)
        -> element002 (id = 2 in Elements table)
    - item-id-bbb (id = 2 in Container_Item table)
        -> element003 (id = 3 in Elements table)
        -> element004 (id = 4 in Elements table)
    - item-id-ccc (id = 3 in Container_Item table)
        -> element005 (id = 5 in Elements table)
        -> element006 (id = 6 in Elements table)
    - item-id-ddd (id = 4 in Container_Item table)
        -> element005 (id = 5 in Elements table)
        -> element007 (id = 7 in Elemens table);
    - item-id-eee (id = 5 in Container_Item table)
        -> element-007 (id = 7 in Elemens table)
```

Using the table CONTAINER_CANDIDATES I make the following connections:

```
        - ContainerName01 contains the following :
            -> item-id-aaa (id = 1 in Container_Item table)
            -> item-id-bbb (id = 2 in COntainer_Item table)
            -> item-id-ccc (id = 3 in COntainer_Item table)
            -> item-id-ddd (id = 4 in COntainer_Item table)
        - ContainerName02 contains the following:
            -> item-id-aaa (id = 1 in Container_Item table)
            -> item-id-eee (id = 5 in COntainer_Item table)
```

So in this way I created all my connections.
Now the question is how can I delete the ContainerName01 and all the items under it (Container Items and Elements under it) so that other Containers (example : ContainerName02) is not affected at all ?

I want to achieve this using an Oracle PL SQL procedure

Comment: In case anybody is wondering `(****)` is not a suppressed expletive. It indicates this line in the pseudo-code:  `-> obtain all elements that are used only by the current container_item  in the current container` (scroll left)

Comment: Not sure what "current container" mean in the **** pseudo-code line.
Does it mean that the element sought can be used by container items of containers other than current?

Comment: Please post create table and insert statements so that I can more easily develop some code for you.

Comment: Is `CampaignName01` meant to be `ContainerName01`? I don't see any CampaignNames.

Comment: Yes, CampaignName01 is ContainerName01 . my typo. sorry

Comment: Agree with SF, it's impossible to answer this question without sample data, and all this `(id = 1 in Container_Item table)` verbiage doesn't help much I'm afraid. Actual SQL will get you some answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is not a really hard problem if you follow good practices.

First, you have two "many-to-many" jump tables (`CONTAINER_CANDIDATES` & `COMPOUNDS`), as orphan row in these will be totally useless, we'll add a `DELETE CASCADE` on them.

```
ALTER TABLE CONTAINER_CANDIDATES
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CC_CONTAINER
   FOREIGN KEY (CONTAINERID)
   REFERENCES CONTAINER (ID)
   ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE CONTAINER_CANDIDATES
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CC_CONTAINER_ITEM
   FOREIGN KEY (CONTAINERITEMID)
   REFERENCES CONTAINER_ITEM (ID)
   ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE COMPOUNDS
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_COMPOUNDS_CONTAINER_ITEM
   FOREIGN KEY (CONTAINERITEMID)
   REFERENCES CONTAINER_ITEM (ID)
   ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE COMPOUNDS
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_COMPOUNDS_ELEMENTS
   FOREIGN KEY (ELEMENTSID)
   REFERENCES ELEMENTS (ID)
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Now, things nearly work by themselves, a small stored procedure to ensure we will not keep unused `CONTAINER_ITEM` and `ELEMENTS` and we are good.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cascaded_delete_container (
    P_CONTAINER_ID VARCHAR2
) IS
BEGIN
        -- remove the master from supplied ID
        -- cascade on CONTAINER_CANDIDATES
    DELETE FROM CONTAINER
    WHERE ID = P_CONTAINER_ID;

        -- remove CONTAINER_ITEM not used in CONTAINER_CANDIDATES
        -- cascade on COMPOUNDS
    DELETE FROM CONTAINER_ITEM
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM CONTAINER_CANDIDATES 
        WHERE CONTAINER_ITEM.ID = CONTAINER_CANDIDATES.CONTAINERITEMID
        );

        -- remove ELEMENTS not used in COMPOUNDS
    DELETE FROM ELEMENTS
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM COMPOUNDS 
        WHERE ELEMENTS.ID = COMPOUNDS.ELEMENTSID
        );

    COMMIT;

END;
/
```

This unsure you never have orphan in any of your table. It use the Cascade to do most of the work and just do a small trim of unused data in the two slave tables.

The only downside is this will not allow you to keep entry in `CONTAINER_ITEM` and `ELEMENTS` if you don't use them.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This really helped me . I was thinking way to complicate in clear procedure .

Comment: @Lucian thanks, sometime answers are more easy than we expect ;) BTW, if you need to keep a bit orphans of `CONTAINER_ITEM` and `ELEMENTS` or just need some performance tuning on big tables, you can run the two `DELETE EXISTS` in a dedicated Prc you run once an hour/night/week.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to achieve this via a procedure the way to go would be to pass the container ID as a parameter and then delete the child entries that you fetched via cursor. As I understood, you need to delete the entries in CONTAINER_CANDIDATES and COMPOUNDS tables first. For example:

```
create or replace procedure delete_container(p_container_id number) is

  -- Get all compound child etries via container ID
  cursor c_get_compounds(cp_container_id number) is
    select comp.id
      from compounds comp, container_candidates cc
     where comp.containerItemID = cc.containerItemID
       and cc.containerID = cp_container_id;

  -- Get all container candidate child entries via container ID
  cursor c_get_container_candidates(cp_container_id number) is
    select cc.id
      from container_candidates cc
     where cc.containerID = cp_container_id;

begin

  -- Fetch all compound entries
  for r in c_get_compounds(cp_container_id => p_container_id) loop
    -- Delete compound entries
    delete from compounds where id = r.id;
  end loop;

  -- Fetch all container candidates
  for r in c_get_container_candidates(cp_container_id => p_container_id) loop
    -- Delete container candidates
    delete from container_candidates where id = r.id;
  end loop;

  -- Delete container entry
  delete from container where id = p_container_id;
end delete_container;
```

Check if ID's are correct in the code

Comment: I would like to delete only the elements and container_items that are used by a specific container . In case one of the elements / container_items is used by other container then they should not be deleted. I have a working PL SQL procedure for this, but it works very slowly. i can have up to 10 milion elemnts (of any kind) in my tables

Comment: Well will need to see your code in order to find out how to improve it.